# Android : Simple HTTPS request and get response

Tags: java, android, sockets, https, connection

I'm creating a android proxy server and i use this for HTTP request :

```
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("perdu.com"), 80);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

out.print("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: perdu.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
out.flush();
```

I doesn't work for HTTPS request, so my question is : How to replace this for SSL working and get server response ?

Thank you

PS: i'm french, sorry for my english :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html I think you would need SSLSockets. I don't have any experience with this myself.

Comment: + of course different port ...

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(domain, 443);

socket.startHandshake();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InpuStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
```